# SignalR - Notify all Clients (apps) on Same Machine

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

**The short version of my question**

Is it possible to utilize signalR to send notifications based on connection endpoint (use socket connection as bradcast identifier)?

**The long one...**

2 clients (apps) on same machine connect to `asp.net core` NOTIFICATION backend (based on `signalR`).
One app broadcasts to all other apps on same machine.
If another app (from same 'family') is launched it recieves the notifications as well. These apps are totally decoupled and are binded based on the machine they ran on.
Since IP address can be same behind network - bind apps using IP address is not an option.

Thank you for time and efforts

Comment: This is not necessary, because every client will generate a unique connectionid when connecting to signalr.

Comment: @Karney. I don't understand your comment- how can I know that 2 clients are on the same machine?

Comment: I don’t know if these two clients do fixed transactions. If so, you can record their ids when connecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a device-specific token and pass it as hub method parameter.

A properly encrypted MAC address would be a choice (I wouldn't recommend passing your MAC address as plaintext as it's extremely dangerous).

After that you can create groups based on these unique device tokens and send messages within groups.

The hub method would be like:

```
public async Task OnEnterSession(string deviceToken)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, deviceToken);
}
```

And you can send device-oriented message by calling:

```
await Clients.Group(deviceToken).SendAsync("clientSideServerCallback", args);
```

I got this idea from Azure Notification Hub Android SDK. I believe your scenario is somehow commensurate with pushing notification to a mobile device.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll check it and response